# I need to check in scala if a number is present in a list /set of numbers and retrieve boolean as a result

Tags: scala

Let `y` be a set or list of numbers, e.g `List(1,2,3,4)` and suppose `val x=1` so i need to check whether `x` is present in `y` collection. In this case boolean result as `true` is expected, and suppose `val x=7` where the result should be `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [contains](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean) to check whether value exists or not.

```
list.contains(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

For sets consider

```
val s = Set(1,2,3,4)

s(1)
Boolean = true
```

a short for set inclusion, implemented by

```
s.apply(1)
Boolean = true
```

Moreover,

```
s(7)
Boolean = false
```

Valid for lists and sets alike (in addition to `contains`) is `exists`, for example,

```
s.exists(_ == 1)
Boolean = true

s.exists(_ == 7)
Boolean = false
```